# How to run Robotframework test cases in a particular order from different suites?

Tags: python, robotframework

We have at least ten test suites each having at least 10 test cases. I would like to know if there is a way to run selected tests from each of the suites in an order I would like?

For example with the following test folder structure:

```
|--------Tests
     |---Suite 1
         |-------Test 1
         |-------Test 2
         |-------Test 3
     |---Suite 2
         |-------Test 1
         |-------Test 2
         |-------Test 3
     |---Suite 3
         |-------Test 1
         |-------Test 2
         |-------Test 3
```

Now I want to run the tests in the order for example as below,

1. Suite 1 - Test Case 3
2. Suite 2 - Test Case 2
3. Suite 1 - Test Case 2
4. Suite 3 - Test Case 3

Please note that the tests are not in any random fashion but has a specific meaning for us. Basically, I have a lot of feature tests separated by specific feature type and each has more tests. Whenever I would like to perform some smoke/sanity tests I would want only certain tests to be executed.

Comment: Does the order really matter? For the smoke/sanity test scope you could add specific tags to test cases you want and then run this narrow scope with `robot --include smoke /Tests`. In this case the order possibly would be S1T2, S1T3, S2T2, S3T3.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the best workaround for this is to use prefixes with underscores, as it is mentioned in the [User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order).

For example:

> 01__my_suite.html -> First test case/suite to be executed.
>
> 02__another_suite.html -> Second test case/suite to be executed.